# Making a pattern finger GUI in android

Tags: android, algorithm, user-interface

I want to make a pattern like which in android! .
the example is like that picture :

[android pattern  http://cdn.guidingtech.com/mobiles/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/set-the-code-by-connecting-the-dots.png](http://cdn.guidingtech.com/mobiles/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/set-the-code-by-connecting-the-dots.png)

so is there any tip or a useful link about such things? ...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: maybe you can look into the CyanogenMod source code.

Comment: I didn't try it yet really, But I wanted to be sure that I have a background on such interface .. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use TabletLayout to divide screen to 3x3

then use onTouch() listener to get the X and Y to check whether your finger is come to those part

ex. if x > 200 & x < 280 && y > 400 y < 480

and now its up to your graphics :]

Comment: Thanks, I Know that idea :D, but I just want something make the graphics to be made easier, But really thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[That](https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/) Android library project extracted the sources from Android framework. You can make use of it or extract it on your own from the [sources](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base)

Comment: I wanted something easier!, but thanks for that hint.

Comment: What do you mean by easier? If that pattern is what you are looking for you do not need to write just one line of code :). Can't be simpler. Maybe just replace the drawables

Comment: I meant that I must include the whole library then read its documentation, then code it :D, I was in need to make it by myslef :) that's what I meant :) .. I hope you got me .. :)

Comment: To be honest..no :). So you want to write it down on your own..but why when it's already there? And in order to include the library this needs an effort of 4-5 clicks and in order to use the funcionality it needs 3 lines of code as described in docs. Haven't used it either but sounds like a easy solution. But anyway :)

Comment: Will try to use it :), thanks a lot for your patience :)...

Comment: Just download the project and add it to your workspace (in Eclipse: Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace). After that you have to rerference that library from your own project. [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html) will guide you how to do it (the passage about "Referencing a library project")